# Google Chrome Reloads page automatically when I open developer tools (inspect element)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, inspect-element

I am having this weird issue with google chrome browser. whenever i try to inspect element and open the developer tools, it automatically reloads the page.
Is there anyone else having the same issue ? How do you solve it ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. Could be also an extension you've installed. Or the site tries to protect itself by detecting devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm , thanks for your comment. I just disabled all extensions and its not reloading anymore. So you are right, its some extension who is doing this.

Comment: What was the extension?

Comment: This behaviour doesn't occur on all websites

Comment: @Osinachi probably an angular extension as this is happening to me and the only new extension I installed recently is an angular extension

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I just solved this today!*  For me, the extension was: *Instagram Download Video & Image* (but there appear to be about 30 affected plugins).  Check the ARS link for all of them...

To quote [ARS Technica](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2020/12/up-to-3-million-devices-infected-by-malware-laced-chrome-and-edge-add-ons/)...

> ...researchers from Prague-based Avast said they found 28 extensions for the Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers that contained malware. The add-ons billed themselves as a way to download pictures, videos, or other content from sites including Facebook, Instagram, Vimeo, and Spotify. At the time this post went live, some, but not all, of the malicious extensions remained available for download from Google and Microsoft.

The plugins have been removed, you can't download them at the chrome plugin site anymore, and the problem of the page refreshing when you inspect no longer happens.

**2021, July Update**: It seems like other extensions are slowly being weeded out as security threats by Google.  Just the other week, the extension *TikTok Video Downloader* was similarly removed.

Comment: in my case it was `My Ruler` extension. When I disabled it, it stopped reloading

Comment: In my case, it was Slick color picker (ID: nbocmbonjfbpnolapbknojklafhkmplk - https://extpose.com/ext/226281)

Comment: I just experienced it today. It was so annoying, I almost uninstalled chrome altogether. Then found the culprit.
For me, it was `Vue JS Devtools`